# switch case construction - although false still goes into case

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$days = 0;
$daysLastChar = mb_substr($days, -1);
switch ($daysLastChar) {
    case in_array($daysLastChar, Array("1")): {
        $correctDaysForm = "день";
        break;
    }
    case in_array($daysLastChar, Array("2", "3", "4")): {
        $correctDaysForm = "дня";
        break;
    }
    case in_array($daysLastChar, Array("5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0")): {
        $correctDaysForm = "дней";
        break;
    }            
}
```

The first case boolean `in_array($daysLastChar, Array("1"))` expression evaluates to `FALSE` and yet the flow enters this case and sets `$correctDaysForm` variable to incorrect first value. Why so? It doesn't happen if the number of days ends with number other than zero.

Comment: As a sidenote, using `mb_substr` when `% 10` should clearly suffice is too overkilly. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *not* how you use a `switch` statement.  `switch` matches the value passed in (`$daysLastChar`) with the values of each of the case statements.

So, it is trying to do `$daysLastChar == in_array($daysLastChar, Array("1"))` (and so on).  `in_array` returns a boolean, and `$daysLastChar` (I assume) is a int.  So, as you can see it won't match the statement that you expect it to.

`switch` uses "loose comparison" (meaning it uses `==` instead of `===`).  So if `$daysLastChar` is `0`, then it will match the first case because `in_array` returns `false`, which has the same *value* as `0`.

One method of doing this is to use `switch(true)`.  So that it will compare `true` with each statement to see which matches.  Or, you can convert this to an `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 1):

you are switching on `$daysLastChar`. therefore if `in_array($daysLastChar, Array("1"))` evaluates to `$daysLastChar` then that case is executed.